# Require.js is loading modules even inside an IF statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs, amd

I'm finding some problems when loading certain .js module via require.js
Problem is: I only need to load certain module in some pages, not the entire website. Therefore I'm placing code this way:

```
if($('.module-news').length > 0 + $('.module-ticket-euromillones-multiple').length + $('.module-news-page').length > 0) {
            require('_modules/news-grid').init();
        }
```

This code search in the HTML if a *class="module-news"* exists (news page). If so, then load the module with the javascript.

That is NOT working. The IF is evaluating correctly, but module *news-grid* is ALWAYS loading no matter .module-news exists or not.

I found out that if I change the string of the module path for a variable, then requires behaves correctly, but that makes no sense. This how, following code works:

var name = "_modules/news-grid";

```
if($('.module-news').length > 0 + $('.module-ticket-euromillones-multiple').length + $('.module-news-page').length > 0) {
                require(name).init();
            }
```

Is this a known issue with require? Am I missing something? (maybe in the requirejs.config settings?

Help appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Solution

You should be using the regular RequireJS idiom for calling `require`:

```
if (...) {
    require(['_modules/news-grid'], function (news_grid) {
        news_grid.init();
    });
}
```

#### Why It Fails

You are using RequireJS' feature which lets you write `require` calls in the CommonJS format `var module = require("module name")`. **You cannot use it for loading modules conditionally.**

The call `require('module name')` (with a string as the first argument rather than a dependency array) is a convenience. It will return a module but if and only if the module is *already loaded*. If the module is not already loaded, then the call will fail. The only reason you don't have to worry about pre-loading the modules before calling `require('module name')` is that RequireJS does it for you.

```
define(function (require) {
    var foo = require('foo');
});
```

is interpreted by RequireJS as:

```
define(['require', 'foo'], function (require) {
    var foo = require('foo');
});
```

It scans the function for calls to `require` in the CommonJS idiom and generates a list of modules that it loads before executing the module. **Conditionals are completely transparent to this process.** Any `require` call with a string as the first parameter will be detected and the module it means to load will be added to the dependencies loaded before `define`'s callback is called...

RequireJS won't detect those cases where something else than a string is passed to `require`. If you write:

```
var name = "foo";
var foo = require(name);
```

RequireJS will not know that you want to load `foo` and will not add `foo` to the list of dependencies. Is this a solution? No, because remember what I said earlier `require('module name')` will return a module, and not fail, only if the module is *already loaded*.

If you want your module to be loaded conditionally, then abandon the CommonJS idiom.